# How to get RSS Feed in to my Website using PHP

Tags: php, rss

I need to put rss feed in to my website using **PHP**. For example, I need to get RSS feed from the following site.

**http://www.ainonline.com/index.php?id=5**

How can i accomplish this.

As i am new bie to RSS i need some professionals help to get a deep knowledge in it.

Hope u pals do...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: http://nirak.net/blog/2008/10/23/embedding-rss-into-a-webpage-using-php/... Here i got the answer... It works perfectly....

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Zend_Feed](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-feed/) class in an MVC project or as a standalone library.

There are examples in the [manual](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-feed/consuming-rss/).

It is as simple as this:

```
$channel = new Zend_Feed_Rss('http://www.ainonline.com/index.php?id=5');
foreach ($channel as $item) {
    echo $item->title();
}
```

Comment: I like the Zend libraries, they have tons of example source to learn from as well

Answer (score 1):

**Update** Here is a site with a bunch of php scripts, including RSS scripts: http://gscripts.net/free-php-scripts/RSS_Scripts.html

If you are wanting to create the entire thing from scratch check this link out. I haven't walked through the whole thing myself, but it seems nice.
http://tiffanybbrown.com/2005/12/22/dynamic-rss-feeds-using-php-mysql-and-apache/

I recommend that you know php and MySql as well as maybe reading a few tutorials about how RSS works.

Also, you could check out the RSS code in WordPress, that's what I did, though It may be a bit complicated to reverse engineer it, versus just reading tutorials and learning it from the ground up correctly.:)

Comment: thanks for your reply Cason... If possible provide me the good working examples form scratch... I googled.. but i can't find the best one....

Answer (score 1):

I found [simplepie](http://simplepie.org/) easy to use and well documented - saves having to understand the details of all the different feed types.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

http://ditio.net/2008/06/19/using-php-curl-to-read-rss-feed-xml/